# Automatic deployment of software to Debian

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I have been reading about creating my own Debian packages for my own software and deploying them to a apt-get repository that I also can create on my own.

The source code for my software is in a Git repository.

My question is how would I automate this process?

The process:

- Increment version number and pre-compile software.
- Package the software in an Debian package with new version number.
- Copy package to apt-get repository.

Another question: Could machines that have my software installed be notified when a new version has arrived at my apt-get repository?